# What is the simplest method to create a plain GUI in C?

Tags: c, user-interface

I am writing a small program for one of my classes that has a lot of repetitious calculations. I want to display information entered by the user in separate fields on the same GUI. What is the simplest possible method for doing something like this? The GUI will only be as complicated as maybe 1 or 2 buttons and the previously mentioned fields. There is no reason for multi-threading to keep the GUI updated - although that probably has little to do with the  GUI libraries.

I have played around a bit with GTK in Linux and it was very simple. Is there something as simple for the Windows environment that does not require much tedious coding as Qt for C?

I have read the the Microsoft IDE Visual Studio has drag-drop type GUI programming. Is C compatible with this method?

Comment: You can get GTK for Windows, too...

Comment: The only information I can find is either for C++ in windows, or GTK for the Linux environment. If it is possible then I will find it, thank you.

Comment: Right here: http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [**glade**](https://glade.gnome.org/). It's a GUI designer that translate your interface to a XML file that you can make a GUI application by using it with GTK.  Also, It's run on Windows/Mac OS too.

> I have read the the Microsoft IDE Visual Studio has drag-drop type GUI
>   programming. Is C compatible with this method?

No, it's not. MS VS use its MS' C++, so-called [**C++/CLI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI).

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it should be pointed out that _both_ C++/CLI and native, unmanaged C++ are amongst the candidates for which a GUI may be 'drag-n-drop' designed using the VS ide. There's nothing I've seen in the past 20 years that excludes win32 programming in C. I do it quite regularly, in fact.